# Read txt file in res/raw/ within Android NDK

Tags: android, file-io, android-ndk

I have a file within my application that I want to have included within the .apk for my android app that is a .txt file.  My application is almost entirely written in C through the use of the NDK, using OpenGL as well.  I know I can bundle the txt file by placing it in /res/raw/, but is there anyway I can access this within the android NDK?

-Thanks

Comment: I don't really want to call on other programs to do this, so I decided to just use a quick hack and open the file in Java and write it to the SDcard.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651816

Answer (score 7):

See the native-audio sample in the NDK. This has code that reads from the assets folder.

Comment: Its not an NDK application thou.