# Reading assets with NDK and Android 2.1

Tags: android, unzip, assets, android-ndk

Since my Android application aims 2.1 versions of the system, I cannot read my assets through the native asset manager provided in the lastest NDK. What I am doing to read these assets is to retrieve the application path with Java, send the path string to my native code and then I unzip it with libzip.

Is it safe, or even the only way to do that on 2.1- systems? Are there limitations through different platforms or security levels?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Resource Files from my own APK in Android Native Environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651816/reading-resource-files-from-my-own-apk-in-android-native-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651816/reading-resource-files-from-my-own-apk-in-android-native-environment/2663962#2663962) recommends either your method or [taking advantage of filenames to avoid compression](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/8274a4c51cc9cc1d). I don't think it would be "unsafe" to use either method.